# Error messages aren't displayed when submitting the form

Tags: 8, ajax, status-messages

I want to display an error message when I submit a form. I added an AJAX callback to the form, and the error message appears after I refreshed the page.

I first tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
$response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();
$message = drupal_get_messages();
$output = $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\PrependCommand(".region-highlighted",$message));
return $output;
```

I also tried the following code.

```
$status_messages = array('#type' => 'status_messages');
$text = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($status_messages);
return $text;
```

Comment: have you found a solution, i got the same problem ... checked all settings and permissions .. but anonymous users won't get the message ..

Comment: did you solve your problem? where did you put your second try?

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the errors with `$form_state->getErrors()`.

So, you should have something like:

```
/**
   * Ajax submit handler.
   *
   * @param array $form
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse
   */
  public function ajaxSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_get_messages();
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    if ($form_state->getErrors()) {
      unset($form['#prefix']);
      unset($form['#suffix']);
      $form['status_messages'] = [
        '#type' => 'status_messages',
        '#weight' => -10,
      ];
      $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#my-id', $form));
    }

    return $response;
  }
```

Check [Examples for Developers](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/ModalForm.php#L156) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

this works for form messages (in a regular ajax form callback):

```
    $form['status_messages'] = [
      '#type' => 'status_messages',
      '#weight' => -10,
    ];
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#yourFormWrapperElement', $form));
```

but using drupal_get_messages() screw's things somehow up .... sometimes. plus you need enable showing messages here: */admin/config/development/logging*

So - your second try should also work !

```
$status_messages = array('#type' => 'status_messages');
$text = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($status_messages);
return $text;
```

Maybe the mentioned settings are needed ..